# I want to rename the table names generated my ASPNET entity framework in .NetCore?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I keep getting the error :
Cannot find the object "UserRoles" because it does not exist...
I want to rename the table "AspNetUserRoles" to "UserRoles". Here is my code in the  OnCreating method in the Application DbContext class

builder.Entity>().ToTable("UserRoles");

Comment: Did you created a migration and applied it on the DB?

Comment: Use `Run custom tool` on `*.tt` files in `edmx`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a little tricky for Identity because of how it use of generics.

1. Add the ToTable mapping for the identity classes.

```
    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext
    {
       protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
       {
          base.OnModelCreating(builder);
          builder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().ToTable("Users");
          builder.Entity<IdentityRole>().ToTable("Roles");
          builder.Entity<IdentityUserRole<string>>().ToTable("UserRoles");
          builder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim<string>>().ToTable("UserClaims");
          builder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin<string>>().ToTable("UserLogins");
          builder.Entity<IdentityRoleClaim<string>>().ToTable("RoleClaims");
          builder.Entity<IdentityUserToken<string>>().ToTable("UserTokens");
       }
    }
```

2. Create a migration

```
dotnet ef migrations add RenameIdentityTables
```

3. Update your database

```
dotnet ef database update
```